# Prove for every function that from sphere to real number has points $x$, $-x$ such that f$(x)=f(-x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have not taken topology course yet. This is just the question that my undergrad research professor left us to think about. She hinted that I could use a theorem from Calculus.
So I reviewed all theorems in Calculus, and I found Intermediate Value Theorem might be helpful(?)... since it has some generalizations on topology. 
But I still don't know how to get started. If you could give me some hints or similar examples, that would be really helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any function this is obviously wrong, it is true  for every continuous function.

Take the function 
$$g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$$ and show that is has a zero (hint $g(x)=-g(-x)$)

Comment: Thanks. So I suppose g(x) is not equal to zero, then g(x)>0 or g(x)<0.

Comment: So f(x)>f(-x) or f(x)<f(-x)? Then to find contradiction to prove g(x)=0?

Comment: @Ashleyjwz did you unterstand it now? yeah thats the way to make it

Answer (score 1):

You may search borsuk–ulam theorem and get some details.

Comment: Can you provide further details in case readers do not have the reference? Regards

Comment: +1 And be sure to accept (click on $\checkmark$) an answer for each question you ask, if it's been helpful (you can accept one answer per question.  ;-)